# gem install failure

Tags: ruby, gem

I am trying to install an instagram-crawler by using the gem command:

gem install instagram-crawler

But I am receiving the following error:

> Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing instagram-crawler:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri /usr/bin/ruby2.5
> ```
>
> -r ./siteconf20190205-5483-1zru4h.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.1/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar thread somewhere. A certain package was missing. By executing the following command everything is fixed:

sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems ruby-dev
```

and afterwards I was able to install my gem. I believe it will do the work for yours too.

I found the answer here: [StackOverflow: Gem Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952622/6778849)